# fixing jumbled css to show checkboxes next to the label

Tags: html, css, simple-form

I can't seem to fix a css issue in my app that maybe has too much jumbled up css.

To isolate the problem I've put partial of the problem on jsbin: http://jsbin.com/asoye3/2/

It includes all the CSS that my app uses.

Problem is that the checkboxes are showing as a group on the right side of the page rather than being next to each label.  I tried using firebug but can't seem to isolate this issue.

Comment: Are the checkboxes supposed to be to the left or the right of each label?

Comment: they should be on the right of each label

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added this to your page in firebug and it seemed to work...

```
 <style type="text/css">span {width:20%; float:left;}</style>
```

Comment: I can not isolate the checkboxes like that since they are being generated using a inbuilt loop (simple_form).  Would have made my life easier if I had more control.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is all labels have `float: left` and the checkboxes don't. Just remove the `float: left` from the labels.

Comment: that fixes the issue, however, if I have 20 checkboxes and want to show 5 in each row then that's not possible if I remove `float: left` I've updated my code on jsbin to reflect this. I tried removing float: left using firebug and everything tries to be in one row.  Also, I can't put a `br` in between checkboxes as they are drawn using simple_form tag